# Windows 7 32-bit Crash Dump Tries to Write To Non-Existent Drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod, crash

I've got a machine that bluescreens, but will not write out any sort of dump file (mini, kernel or otherwise). I've fiddled with the swap file so it be large enough to handle the dump. Only the C:\ drive is defined on the machine, so the potential issue of having the swap file on a different drive is not a factor.

Checking the event log, there an entry which corresponds to the BSOD that reads:

*"Crash dump initialization failed"*

In the details for this event, there is a reference to the hard drive. Presumably, this is where the dump would have been written to:

*\Device\HarddiskVolume2*

However, there is only one physical hard drive and a single partition/volume defined. The System Information utility (msinfo32.exe) shows the drive name to be:

*\Device\HarddiskVolume1*

Seems like Windows the crash dump is failing as it wants to write onto "Volume2", which does not exist.

I'm wondering if the *\Device\HarddiskVolume2* string might be editable and could be changed to *\Device\HarddiskVolume1*? Registry, BIOS and the other usual locations have been checked, but with (unsurprisingly) no luck. I'm out of ideas.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl
```

You'll find several entries, such as `DumpFile` and `MinidumpDir`

Typically, the default location is defined by the environment variable `SystemRoot`...

I believe the registry also contains the default `SystemRoot` value here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot
```

If those variables aren't pointing to the correct location, it's possible that your mount points are screwed up.  Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` under `\DosDevice\C:` (probably) and make sure the binary data is pointing to the correct volume.  (Sorry, the reg-value is in "REG_BINARY" format... but you should be able to convert the hex to ascii to make it readable.)

Comment: The registry entries are all present and pointing at valid folders. Made sure the %SystemRoot% variable expands to the correct windows location (i.e. C:\Windows). The MountedDevices key/folder does contain a number of entries.  But after decoding the hex, they were all just mounts for USD drive that must have been inserted into the machine.

Comment: I think we need to know how and where windows uses "Device\HarddiskVolumeX" and maps it to a drive letter.  I've done some looking into NTFS mounting points and symbolic links, but these don't seem like likely suspects.

Comment: Which registry were you looking at? ... the one in the recovery disk? or the one for the OS that keeps blue-screening?  You probably need to load the registry of the broken system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry for the default folder for crash dumps.

This is found under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl`.
The values of these should be:

- `MinidumpDir` : `%SystemRoot%\Minidump`
- `DumpFile` : `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP`

You may also do so via *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings*,
Advanced tab, under Startup and Recovery click the Settings button,
set "Dump file" to `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP` and click OK.

Comment: Yep, I've checked those locations and they are correct.  Also made sure the %SystemRoot% variable expands to the correct windows location (i.e. C:\Windows).

Comment: Nave you disabled the pagefile or reduced it? Windows needs this file to create crash dumps, and it should be large enough to contain the dump across the reboot.

Comment: The machine has 4GB of memory.  I've set the page file to use 5000MB - 19000MB.

Comment: Full dump or minidump?

Comment: Tried both mini and kernel.

Comment: Last try: Set the file size to equal the RAM.